# Javascript/jQuery - replace a video iframe with a placeholder image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've had one question involving this piece of code answered by the very helpful people here, but now I have another one which is slightly different. I have a placeholder image which sits in a carousel slide, which when clicked on gets replaced by a youtube video using the default youtube iframe embed.

What I would like to do is, after a user has clicked on the image and has played the video, when they click away from the carousel slide the video is embedded in (for example, by clicking on a carousel arrow or pagination dot) it resets it back to how it was before the video was displayed.

I hope that makes sense. Basically, I need help reverse engineering this code so that the video gets replaced again by it's placeholder image on a click of another element/div.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="youtube_video">
<img src="img/video_poster_carousel.jpg" width="986" height="308">
<!-- <iframe width="986" height="555" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Wt_Ruy_ejPY?enablejsapi=1&list=PL027E2B6D9900A88F&showinfo=0&controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
/* video */
.youtube_video { position: relative; padding-bottom: 31.65%; height:0;  }
.youtube_video img { position: absolute; display: block; top: 0; left: 0; /*width: 100%; height: 100%;*/ z-index: 20; cursor: pointer; }
.youtube_video:after { content: ""; position: absolute; display: block; 
    background: url(play-button.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    top: 45%; left: 45%; width: 46px; height: 36px; z-index: 30; cursor: pointer; } 
.youtube_video iframe { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;  }

/* image poster clicked, player class added using js */
.youtube_video.player img { display: none; }
.youtube_video.player:after { display: none; }
```

And the Javascript:

```
  $(function() { 
    var videos  = $(".youtube_video");

        videos.on("click", function(){
            var elm = $(this),
                conts   = elm.contents(),
                le      = conts.length,
                ifr     = null;

            for(var i = 0; i<le; i++){
              if(conts[i].nodeType == 8) ifr = conts[i].textContent;
            }

            elm.addClass("player").html(ifr);
            elm.off("click");
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This below line actually does a innerHTML which means your img tag is lost
you may have to move the IMG tag out of the youtube_video container and do a hide and show toggle mechanism for the   youtube_video container and the IMG  tag

```
elm.addClass("player").html(ifr);
```

Comment: Hmmm, you may well be right. I might have to figured out the easiest and quickest way of doing this without changing too much at this late stage. Thank you.

Comment: You were indeed correct! I changed the functionality to more of a hide/show toggle approach, and I was able to do what I needed to do a hundred times easier than my previous approach. Thank you. Sometimes you just need do a complete rethink.

Comment: @MattPollard Glad i was able to help!! Cheers!!